# uitableview with a divider

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I am trying to make a uitableview that kind of look like this

[image]

I am not sure how are they doing this? It looks like uitableview with grouped static cells but I am not sure how they inserted a divider and a uitextfield on the right hand side. Any suggestions?

Comment: I understand its a grouped tableview but how did they get a middle line and how did they get lables on the left align like that?

Comment: UITableViewCell is a subclass of a UIView  and you can draw inside it. Example: suppose you have an image for viewing the vertical line, you can do UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageName:@"verticalLine.png]]" [cell addSubview:imgView]; for eaxh line you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done in storyboard, designing the "Prototype Cell" of the grouped table view. Just put in the text field, position and style it to your liking.

For the separator line, you could either draw to a view (which is a bit complicated for a beginner) or  simply insert a `UIView` at the appropriate place. Set its background color as you wish and set the width to 1.0. -- Violà!

Answer (score 0):

In the -cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method, you can add views to the cell's contentView property.  In your case, an image for the separator and then an appropriate text field.